# Handling error in promise - Es6

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6, promise

I have a pretty simple code that's as follows

```
return Location.findById(locationId)
  .then(doc => {
    if(doc) {
      console.log('Found a matching record.....proceed to delete');
      return Location.remove({_id: locationId});
    } else {
      const err = new Error(`${locationId} item you wish to delete does not exist!`);
      err.status = 500;
      throw err;
      // return next(err);
    }
  })
  .then(deletedDoc => {
    console.log('Record deleted');
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: `${locationId} is DELETED`,
      deletedDoc
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Caught error in catch BLOCK", err);
    return res.status(500).status({
      message: `We are having problems deleting this ${locationId}!`
    });
  });
```

As you can see from the code above, error is thrown from 'then'. Although error is captured in 'catch', front-end application never receives any response from 'catch'. Alternatively, if I comment out 'throw error' piece and uncomment 'return next(err)', application works fine. BTW, I have a  global error handler in 'app.js'.

```
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      handler: 'GLOBAL',
      message: error.message
    }
  })
});
```

I checked to see if I am lost 'res' object in the process of throwing error. console.log(res) seem to have the object intact. Interestingly, When I execute this above code that throws error in nodeJS console, but POSTMAN time's out. Can someone explain why this behavior and help me understand this situation better?

BTW, I am aware there is a findByIDAndRemove or similar methods in mongoose. I find it hard to move on, without understanding why the code works the way it does. I'd appreciate all of your help.

Comment: FYI, `findById()` followed by `.remove()` is subject to race conditions (the object could be found, but then modified or removed before you call remove()).  `findByIdAndRemove()` or something similar could be atomic and not subject to race conditions.  Atomic operations are nearly always preferred with databases.

Comment: Why you run this code from Postman, what exactly logs in the server?  This is a problem you need to debug and find out where your server code goes hawwire.  I don't see anything obvious in the code you've shown that would fail to send a response back.  When you say it "throws error in nodeJS console,", what EXACTLY do you see in the console?

Comment: Message I see in console is "Caught error in catch BLOCK". Record seems to have been deleted from DB. But POSTMAN time's out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't sending the response from your `.catch()` block because you're using `.status()` instead of `.json()`.  Change this:

```
return res.status(500).status({
  message: `We are having problems deleting this ${locationId}!`
});
```

to this:

```
return res.status(500).json({
  message: `We are having problems deleting this ${locationId}!`
});
```

Comment: That was terribly silly of me. This is what happens when we don't take a break and keep punching in some code. thanks. That will fix my issue for sure. COFFEE please